# Считывание цвета заднего фона

Tags: java, android, background, color, background-color

Как считать цвет заднего фона элемента?
Я создал приложение и мне нужно заменить цвет заднего фона на другой используя if-else
Для примера: есть 3 элемента при нажатии на 1-го с них открываеться окно с синим цветом и с определенными элементами, при нажатии на 2-й открываеться **тоже самое** окно но с красным цветом и с другими элементами, но как считать задний фон, я не знаю...
Пробывал так:

```
if(bgColor.equals("#FFFF")){
//text.setText("1");
}
```

Мне нужно считать цвет, а не подставлять по нажатию так как у меня по дргому код работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, у вас есть `containerView` цвета `#EBAEBA`, в котором есть `textView`:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    ...
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:background="#EBAEBA">

    <TextView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Чтобы вычитать цвет фона контейнера, нужно привести фон к типу `ColorDrawable`, далее вытащить цвет фона и сравнить его числовым значением цвета `#EBAEBA`:

```java
ColorDrawable background = (ColorDrawable) containerView.getBackground();
if (background.getColor() == Color.parseColor("#EBAEBA")) {
    textView.setText("Цвет #EBAEBA");
} else {
    textView.setText("Другой цвет");
}
```